# SQL Server: how to create temp table with auto increment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to create a temp table with an auto increment and insert data. The table is created correctly, but I cannot import the data.

If I just omit the ID table it works correctly, but I need to have the temp table have an ID that we can reference.

The errors I get are:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

My code:

```
SET @strFileName = 'file.txt';
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

CREATE TABLE #UUID
(
      id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      cuuid NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL
);

SET @strSQL = 'BULK INSERT #UUIDFROM ''' + @strFileName + ''' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';

EXEC @intErr = sp_executesql @strSQL;
```

I wonder if it's trying to insert into the the id row instead of the cuuid row...

Any ideas?

Comment: Not familiar with this RDBMS, but can BULK INSERT take a target column list? If so, just enumerate the real columns and the auto-increment column should be filled fwithith the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you have an extra column in the database that is not in the data file, then the solution is a view.  Alas, I don't think you can do this with a temp table.

With a regular table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_UUID (
 id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 cuuid NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW temp_UUID_v as
    SELECT cuuid
    FROM temp_UUID;

SET @strSQL = 'BULK INSERT temp_UUID_V FROM ''' + @strFileName + ''' WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC @intErr= sp_executesql @strSQL;
```

Comment: A [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) could be used, no?

Comment: If it's auto increment why would i need the field in the text file?

Comment: @stephen.vakil . . . I find format files so hard to use in SQL Server that I just simply avoid them.